# Nested for loop error with !null checking an element that doesn't exist

Tags: java, for-loop

I am currently using nested for loops in a 2D array of size 4,2.
When I run my program, I get index out of bounds Exception on the following line

```
  else if (state[i][j+1] != null 
           && state[i][j].getFlash() <= state[i][j].getCycleLength() 
           && state[i][j+1].getCycleLength() == state[i][j].getCycleLength()){
  }
```

It says the index out of bounds is 2. I would understand the error if I wasn't checking to see if [i][j+1] wasn't null, but I don't understand the exception with the check? I tried moving around the !null check but the program still fails on this line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Stack trace:
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at NatComp.data$1.run(data.java:67)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? And some more code showing initialization of your array?

Comment: Try not to put too much conditions on and if sentence. Also, try to program in an object-oriented way that prevents you from using if statements.

Comment: Where are your loops? The problem is most likely with using `j+1` as an index when `j` is at the last legal index.

Comment: Can you advise further Luis? How would you do this? I have been OOP for a year or 2 now and find if statements unavoidable at times (such as this).

Comment: If `state[i][j+1]` tries to read `state[0][2]` on an array dimensioned as `state[4][2]` it is out of bounds as the array index is 0 based. Checking for `null` does not help on a value that you cannot read.

Comment: rsp- Is there a way I can check if a cell exists then without checking if its null?

Comment: `if (j+1 >= state[i].length)` ... if this returns true, then you'll get an IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to access `state[i][j+1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Just checking for `state[i][j+1] != null` prevents `NullPointerException`, but it does not prevents the code from raising an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

For checking the `IndexOutOfBounds`, you need to check your `indices` against the maximum allowable index. There is not point in relying on checking the elements with null. You won't even be able to access the elements, if the index is out of bounds, so the `null` check might not even be `checked`.

Also, if you have so many conditions in your `if`, its better to separate them in `nested` if, with the outer `if` checking for `IndexOutOfBounds`, and inner `if` doing the actual condition check. That would be more readable.

**For e.g.,** if you have an array declared as `new int[3]`, then before accessing an index, you can add a check for: -

```
if (index < 3) {
     // you can now access `array[index]`, as it is safe now
     // Also, you can add a check for `NPE` here.
}
```

That's because your indices are 0-based. So maximum accessible index is `max - 1`, where `max` is the size of your array.

You can adapt the same logic in your `array of array`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Think I will be able to sort it now (hopefully).

Comment: don't use magic numbers though, to get the size of a 2D array you should check both dimensions.  E.g. array.length and array[n].length

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty clear from your description that `j==1` when you get the exception. When that happens, `state[i][j+1]` would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` rather than evaluate to `null` as you seem to expect.

The only value of `j` for which your code won't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is zero, so you might want to check for that instead of checking for `null`.

Comment: The stack trace is:
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at NatComp.data$1.run(data.java:67)
 at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
 at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

Comment: Is there a way I can check if a cell exists then without checking if its null?